# OS X: BSD `find /etc` prints just `/etc`

Tags: find, osx

`find` fails to list the contents of the `/etc` directory when invoked in the obvious way and I'm not sure what the explanation is.

`find /etc` just shows `/etc`, even though there are other files inside the directory.

```
$ find /etc
/etc
```

also

```
$ find /./etc
/./etc
```

and as root

```
$ sudo find /etc
/etc
```

However, I can see some files inside `/etc` when I run `find /etc/.`

```
$ find /etc/. | head
find: /etc/./cups/certs: Permission denied
/etc/.
/etc/./afpovertcp.cfg
/etc/./afpovertcp.cfg~orig
/etc/./aliases
```

Other commands such as `ls` show contents of `/etc`...

```
$ ls -1 /etc | head
afpovertcp.cfg
afpovertcp.cfg~orig
aliases
aliases.db
```

Is this expected behavior for `find`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On OSX, `/etc` is a symbolic link, and `find` won't traverse that as if it were a directory.

For what it's worth, `/tmp` and `/var` also are symbolic links (pointing in each case to subdirectories of `/private`).

You could use (see [POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)) the `-H` or `-L` options to get something like your intention.

Comment: D'oh. forgot to check that. Then why is `/etc/.` traversable?

Comment: That's because your path points to a real directory (not a symbolic link :-)

Comment: So, by default, `find` will follow symlinks when resolving a path given as a command line argument, but won't when traversing the file system after the initial path has been resolved?

Comment: No.  When you enter `/etc/.` you have forced the symlink to be dereferenced;  the "." directory is the target of the symlink.  So `find` doesn't even see the symlink.  You can see you've dereferenced the symlink by doing `ls -lid /etc/. /private/etc` and note the inode number is the same